# Может ли определитель матрицы размера 9 x 9 с элементами из множества {–1, 1} быть равным 31? 32?

Tags: python, распараллеливание

Необходимо как можно эффективнее решить данное задание на Python. Свои размышления начала с простой идеи:
с помощью декартова произведения получить и перебрать все возможные варианты элементов матрицы, (которых должно быть 81) состоящих из 1 и -1. Далее полученные списки преобразовать в матрицы размера 9*9 и вычислить определители каждой такой матрицы. Таким образом, перебрав все варианты можно наверняка либо получить результат 31 или 32 или нет. Но возникает проблема в операции декартового произведения, такой подход очень долгий, а смысл заключается в том, чтобы код работал как можно эффективнее, но я не знаю, что с этим делать... Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить это задание быстрее, может параллельное выполнение кода необходимо?
Мой код на Python:

```python
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
for tple in product([1, -1], repeat = 81): # декартово произведение
    lst = list(tple) # преобразуем кортеж в список
    print(lst)
    np_lst = np.array(lst) # преобразуем список в массив numpy
    A = np_lst.reshape(9,9) # преобразование в матрицу
    print(A)
    print("Определитель: ", np.linalg.det(A))
```

Comment: Вы осознаёте, что возможных матриц 2^81? Поищите алгебраический путь.

Comment: @MBo мне ваш комментарий никак не помог, т.к. не несет полезной для меня информации

Comment: Ну что ж... Полезная информация - параллельное вычисление не поможет.

Comment: Как можно эффективнее: `return False`

Answer (score 1):

Пара свойств определителей, можно изучить на первом курсе или посмотреть в википедии:

- если одну строку добавить к другой, значение определителя не изменится
- если элементы строки имеют общий множитель, его можно вынести как коэффициент перед определителем

Раз у нас есть такие мощные правила, воспользуемся ими: прибавим первую строку ко всем остальным. Что получается в восьми строках? Чётные числа. Выносим из каждой строки множитель 2, и перемножаем восемь двоек - получается, что определитель такой матрицы всегда кратен 256, т.е. возможные значения: 0, 256, -256, 512, -512, 768...  Ясно, что ни 31, ни 32 здесь не встретятся.

32 может быть значением определителя подобной матрицы размером до 6x6

Python даже не пригодился - разве что `2**8` можно вычислить.

Comment: да, я понимаю, можно рассуждать таким образом, но задание заключается именно в реализации кода эффективным образом, чтобы за адекватное время перебрать все возможные варианты.

Comment: Не знаю, представляете ли вы, сколько времени нужно на генерацию и перебор  2^81 матриц - не менее  2^51~=2*10^15 секунд~70 миллионов лет.

Comment: по поводу ваших рассуждений, вы не учли, что в матрице также могут быть значения -1.

Comment: @JessJ, учли. 0 в данном контексте тоже чётное число.

Comment: @MBo Не 5*5, а 6*6. Ну, в 5*5 наверное тоже, там делители 16 получаются.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Да, точно.